# How can I send requests via HTTP Post to URL in php

Tags: php

I have website that has page for donation.
Merchants registered on the Gateway are to send transaction requests to GTPay via HTTP Post to URL https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPay/Tranx.aspx

When I submit my request I see this page of the above URL displayed inside my donation page instead of taking me to the URL
Below is my code:

```
$url = 'https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPay/Tranx.aspx';
$fields = array(
        'gtpay_mert_id' => urlencode($gtpay_mert_id),
        'gtpay_tranx_id' => urlencode($gtpay_tranx_id),
        'gtpay_tranx_amt' => urlencode($gtpay_tranx_amt),
        'gtpay_tranx_curr' => urlencode($gtpay_tranx_curr),
        'gtpay_cust_id' => urlencode($gtpay_cust_id),
        'gtpay_tranx_noti_url' => urlencode($gtpay_tranx_noti_url),
        'gtpay_hash' => urlencode($gtpay_hash)
    );


//url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $form_files=array();
    $form_options=array( 'cookies' => array( 'auth' => $auth ) );
    http_post_fields($url, $fields, $form_files, $form_options);
//open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Request made using cURL won't take you to the URL. It will just process the request and return data back to your end.

You need to submit your request using an HTML form with your fields.

Something like this:

```
<form action=" https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPay/Tranx.aspx" method="post">

<!-- Saved buttons use the "secure click" command -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">

<!-- Saved buttons are identified by their button IDs -->
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="221">

<!-- Saved buttons display an appropriate button image. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @harunur. The donation amount entered is to be multiplied by 100 and the  value of the parameter gtpay_hash( a hidden field in the form) to be submitted is supposed to be sha512 of a concatenation of the values of the following parameters of the form. gtpay_mert_id,gtpay_tranx_id,gtpay_tranx_amt,gtpay_tranx_curr,gtpay_cust_id,gtpay_tranx_noti_url,hashkey. How do I get the values entered in the form, perform the hash on those values and assign to the hidden parameter and submit to the url along with the other values entered in the form?

Comment: in that case you can serve another form to the user during checkout process.Collect all info then push your values to the payment form and do an javascript form submit .